# How to fix hanging popen3 in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, popen3

I am getting unexpected behaviour using popen3, which I want to use to run a command like tool ala `cmd < file1 > file2`. The below example hangs, so that `stdout done` is never reached. Using other tools than `cat` may cause hanging, so that `stdin done` is never reached. I suspect, I am suffering from buffering, but how do I fix this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'open3'

Open3.popen3("cat") do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
  stdin.puts "foobar"

  puts "stdin done"

  stdout.each_line { |line| puts line }

  puts "stdout done"

  puts wait_thr.value
end

puts "all done"
```

Comment: I've added the `popen3` tag.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`stdout.each_line` is waiting for further output from `cat` because `cat`'s output stream is still open. It's still open because `cat` is still waiting for input from the user because its input stream hasn't been closed yet (you'll notice that when you open `cat` in a terminal and type in `foobar`, it will still be running and waiting for input until you press `^d` to close the stream).

So to fix this, simply call `stdin.close` before you print the output.

Comment: Thanks. I did test this, and it works nicely on this example. However on my real-life stuff it still hangs, but that is also using threads (and using temporary files instead of popen3 works fine). Perhaps popen3 is not thread-safe?

Comment: This fix works only if the argument to `stdin.puts` is short. If you write much, much more data to the pipe associated with your variable `stdin`, `cat` will write to the buffer of the pipe for stdout until the buffer is full. At this moment, the OS will suspend `cat`. If you write more data to your `stdin` in this situation, you fill the buffer of the stdin pipe. When this pipe is full, calling `stdin.puts` blocks. This means: Your program hangs.

So if you have much data, you have to interleave writing to `stdin` and reading from `stdout` (and `stderr`). Why not use `Open3.capture*`?

Comment: @maasha `popen3` is thread-safe. Though you need profound knowledge of inter-process communication to use it right in real life scenarios.

Answer (score 7):

**Your code is hanging, because `stdin` is still open!**

You need to close it with `IO#close` or with `IO#close_write` if you use `popen3`.

If you use `popen` then you need to use `IO#close_write` because it only uses one file descriptor.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby
 require 'open3'

 Open3.popen3("cat") do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
   stdin.puts "foobar"

   stdin.close   # close stdin like this!  or with stdin.close_write

   stdout.each_line { |line| puts line }

   puts wait_thr.value
 end
```

See also:

[Ruby 1.8.7 IO#close_write](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/IO.html#method-i-close_write)

[Ruby 1.9.2 IO#close_write](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/IO.html#method-i-close_write)

[Ruby 2.3.1 IO#close_write](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-close_write)

Comment: This, of course, depends on whether or not the process you are piping to writes to stdout upon an EOT from stdin.  If the process writes to stdout upon every line it gets, then it's possible that something else is causing the hang.

Answer (score 7):

The answers by Tilo and by sepp2k are right: If you close `stdin`, your simple test will end. Problem solved.

Though in your comment to the [answer of sepp2k](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8952073/601203), you indicate that you still experience hangs.
Well, there are some traps that you might have overlooked.

#### Stuck on full buffer for stderr

If you call a program that prints more to stderr than the buffer of an anonymous pipe can hold (64KiB for current Linuxes), the program gets suspended. A suspended program neither exits nor closes stdout. Consequently, reading from its stdout will hang. So if you want to do it right, you have to use threads or `IO.select`, non-blocking, unbuffered reads in order to read from both stdout and stderr in parallel or by turns without getting stuck.

#### Stuck on full buffer for stdin

If you try to feed more (much more) than "foobar" to your program (`cat`), the buffer of the anonymous pipe for stdout will get full. The OS will suspend `cat`. If you write even more to stdin, the buffer of the anonymous pipe for stdin will get full. Then your call to `stdin.write` will get stuck. This means: You need to write to stdin, read from stdout and read from stderr in parallel or by turns.

#### Conclusion

Read a good book (Richards Stevens, "UNIX Network Programming: Interprocess communications") and use good library functions. IPC (interprocess communications) is just too complicated and prone to indeterministic run-time behavior. It is for too much hassle to try to get it right by try-and-error.

Use `Open3.capture3`.